# Set the encoding to ANSI in PowerShell 2.0

Tags: powershell, encoding, powershell-2.0, ansi, powershell-cmdlet

I want to set the encoding of a file to ANSI using the parameter `-Encoding` of the `Set-Content` cmdlet, I tried this one but it didn't work:

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath "$filePath" -Encoding Default
```

Answer (score 10):

PowerShell v2 doesn't recognize an argument `Default` for the parameter `-Encoding`. Use the argument `Ascii` to save a file with ANSI encoding:

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath "$filePath" -Encoding Ascii
```

or omit the parameter entirely (`Set-Content` defaults to ANSI encoding):

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath "$filePath"
```

Comment: I've tried this one but when I open the output file I see that it's encoded in UCS-2 littleEndian

Comment: @ZakariaBelghiti That's clearly not possible. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Not sure if there is a way around but I get the following message: `Set-Content : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Value.` I only want to change encoding not the content. Is there a different command.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `.NET` `WriteAllText` function for that:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($filePath, (Get-Content $filePath))
```

Ensure the default encoding reflects your desired output using:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default
```

Otherwise, add the enum with the desired encoding as the third parameter.

Comment: It didn't work, it says that the parameter -raw couldn't be found, maybe it's not supported in PowerShell 2.0

Comment: ah okay, try to use the get-content without it

Comment: what encoding do you get?

Comment: UCS-2 littleEndian

Answer (score 0):

The question actually works.  Note that ANSI is not ASCII, but is windows-1252 encoding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 (see also iso-8859-1).  It doesn't have a BOM.  This is the powershell 5.1 default (with some exceptions like out-file or ">", which is utf16).  Powershell 7 defaults to utf8 no bom.

```
echo á | set-content foo -Encoding Default
cat foo
á


echo á | set-content foo -Encoding ascii
cat foo
?
```