# Convert text file to ANSI format

Tags: powershell, text, unicode, encoding, ansi

I am running two Powershell scripts. One Powershell script adds the host name to a text file. Other Powershell script appends the ip address of the machine to the same file.
So, the .txt file looks as follows:
hostname
ipaddress
But, this file is being saved in Unicode format by default. What can I do so that, the text file is stored in ANSI format?

I use
    PowerShell v2.0.

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default 

IsSingleByte : True
BodyName : iso-8859-1 
EncodingName : Western European (Windows) 
HeaderName : Windows-1252 
WebName : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay : True
IsBrowserSave : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave : True
EncoderFallback : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly : True 
CodePage : 1252
```

Comment: What PowerShell version do you use? What does `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default` return? How do you write to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solved my problem:

Out-File 'file.txt' -Append -Encoding Ascii

This enabled me to save the file in ANSI format.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how you are outputting your text you may need to set the encoding type. Using `Out-File -Encoding` you use the type of `ASCII`. This also depends on the version of Powershell you're using.

See: [SS64 Out-File](https://ss64.com/ps/out-file.html) and [Set the encoding to ANSI in PowerShell 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37701436/6137709)